# I'm trying to change the color of a sprite when "space" is pressed but I want it to remain red for two seconds and than change back to blue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Action : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    public Color colorA = Color.red;
    public Color colorB = Color.blue;


    void Start()
    {
        sr=GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            sr.color = colorA;
        }
        else sr.color = colorB;
    }
}
```

This is the script I wrote. At first the sprite is blue and when SPACE is pressed it turns red, but the problem is that it doesn't stay red for more than a fraction of a second, sometimes it doesn't even turn red.

Comment: do you want it to remain red as long at space is hold or just wait for two seconds after space is pressed the first time?

Comment: I want it to remain red for one second after space is pressed and then turn back to blue

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that int the fixed update, with `GetKeyDown` that returns true during the frame the user starts pressing down the key, you are setting the color, and the next frame you are turning it back.
Try with a coroutine, where you set the color back two seconds after.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        sr.color = colorA;
        StartCoroutine(setColorWithDelay(2f));
    }
   
}

IEnumerator setColorWithDelay(float delay) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    sr.color = colorB;
}
```

Moreover, as commented `FixedUpdate` is used for physics. Use the `Update` instead.

Comment: Btw, Shouldn't keypresses and UI changes be handled in `Update`?

Comment: It still only stays red for a fraction of a second